# Databox - Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating an app for Android phones using Jquery mobile(1.2.0) [Working offline]. I am using Datebox.. so downloaded and linked the 1.7.1 version of datebox css files, which is restricting me to use only the later versions of the css and js files and not the stable version 1.2.0..

Checked the jquery mobile site and there is no 1.2.0 version of datebox js files.. I dont want to Insert so many css and js files..  So, How can I go about it guys?